# SelectSingleNode always returns null?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, namespaces, selectsinglenode

Taking this simplifed example of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message xmlns="http://www.mydomain.com/MyDataFeed" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mydomain.com/MyDataFeed https://secure.mydomain/MyDataFeed/myDataFeed.xsd" requestId="13898" status="1">
<error>Invalid Login</error>
</message>
```

I am trying to select the 'error' node using SelectSingleNode method, however using the following code it always returns NULL?

```
XmlNode errorNode = oss.SelectSingleNode("/message/error");
if (errorNode != null)
     Console.Writeline("There is an error");
```

From research I have done this is related to namespaces but I simply can't get anything to work. Any advice?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're missing the XML namespace defined by the `<message>` node in your `SelectSingleNode`  call. Assuming `oss` is an `XmlDocument` instance, you need to do this:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(oss.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.mydomain.com/MyDataFeed");

XmlNode errorNode = oss.SelectSingleNode("/ns:message/ns:error", nsMgr);
```

Marc