# What is wrong with this file or code?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xelement, selectsinglenode

What is happening \ what is the difference ?
I'm trying to return a specific node from an XML File.

### XML File:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <JMF SenderID="InkZone-Controller" Version="1.2">
      <Command ID="cmd.00695" Type="Resource">
        <ResourceCMDParams ResourceName="InkZoneProfile" JobID="K_41">
          <InkZoneProfile ID="r0013" Class="Parameter" Locked="false" Status="Available" PartIDKeys="SignatureName SheetName Side Separation" DescriptiveName="Schieberwerte von DI" ZoneWidth="32">
            <InkZoneProfile SignatureName="SIG1">
              <InkZoneProfile Locked="False" SheetName="S1">
                <InkZoneProfile Side="Front" />
              </InkZoneProfile>
            </InkZoneProfile>
          </InkZoneProfile>
        </ResourceCMDParams>
      </Command>
<InkZoneProfile Separation="Cyan" ZoneSettingsX="0 0,005 " />
    </JMF>
```

Code:

```
           XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load("C:\\test\\test.xml");
            XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            var parent = root.SelectSingleNode("/JMF/Command/ResourceCmdParams/InkZoneProfile/InkZoneProfile/InkZoneProfile/InkZoneProfile");

            XmlElement IZP = xmlDoc.CreateElement("InkZoneProfile");
            IZP.SetAttribute("Separation", x.colorname);
            IZP.SetAttribute("ZoneSettingsX", x.colorvalues);
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(IZP);
            xmlDoc.Save("C:\\test\\test.xml");
```

The var parent returns me null. I've debugged , and root and xmlDoc have on their inner text the XML Content.
But, a test made here(made by user @har07 , on the previous question: 
[SelectSingleNode returns null even with namespace managing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676471/selectsinglenode-returns-null-even-with-namespace-managing/35676513)
Worked without problems.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/vJ8h9S

What is the difference between those two ? They follow the same code basically, but one works and other doesn't.
When debugging i've found that root.InnerXml has the contents loaded on itself (same as XmlDoc.InnerXml ). But InnerXml doesn't implement a method to SelectSingleNode. I believe that if i save it to a string i'll probably lose indentation and etc.

Can someone tell me what is the difference or what is wrong ? Thanks !
XML Sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwU9_GrFRYrTUFhMYWk5blhhZWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe that's because of `&` characters in your XML. `&` is [special character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents) in XML which need to be escaped. In the demo I linked to, I have removed all `&` characters to make it work, otherwise `LoadXml()` will throw exception

Comment: @Pablo it is an error in the code you create this line: `<InkZoneProfile Separation=...` post it here and I will point you how to fix.

Comment: @Sakura check the edit

Comment: Sorry it looks horrible.  I'm on my phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetAttribute` don't auto escape string for you. Therefore it make your XML file invalid.

From MSDN about [XmlElement.SetAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1ah1zbw(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Any markup, such as syntax to be recognized as an entity reference, is treated as literal text and needs to be properly escaped by the implementation when it is written out

Find in your code all line contain `SetAttribute` and use `SecurityElement.Escape` to escape the value.

For example: Change these lines:

```
IZP.SetAttribute("Separation", x.colorname);
IZP.SetAttribute("ZoneSettingsX", x.colorvalues);
```

To:

```
using System.Security;

IZP.SetAttribute("Separation", SecurityElement.Escape(x.colorname));
IZP.SetAttribute("ZoneSettingsX", SecurityElement.Escape(x.colorvalues));
```

If an attribute have name contains any of `<>"'&` you also have to escape it like the value.

**Note:**

You have to delete current xmls you create used the old code, because it is invalid, when you load it will cause exception.

Comment: I got it. But all my attributes defined using XMLWriter have double quotes. Not only those two. I'm trying to figure out a way to replace them. I believe that if i convert to string, replace, then convert back to XML i may lose identing.

Comment: @PabloCosta Of course all attributes have double quotes around the value. It is the standar. the synstax of an attributes is `name="value"`

Comment: Yeah i know it. But the dotnetfiddle sample worked without using double quotes. Also i may have characaters like & like an attribute value. The main trouble is that i can't get the specific node i'm looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by don't have double quote + have `&` char? Do you mean you want a xml note like this `<node att=this & that>`

Comment: No. If you see the dontnetfiddle sample , it has no double quotes on it(only single quotes). Like <bla id='1'></bla> . And i believe thats why i can't read the xml node i'm looking for.

Comment: Could you post the XML sample you mentioned?

Comment: please check my edit. I added the dotnetfiddle sample and the XML sample.

Comment: Ok I see. You don't have to worry about single quote or double quotes. It is boundary of the value. What I say is what characters inside that boundary. Follow my suggest above and you will have valid XML file. Also, if an attribute contains any of following string, it still OK: `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;`, `&apos;`, `&amp;`

Comment: I already followed your suggestion. But it didn't changed the scenario. The var parent is still null. And i need it to reach the SpecificSingle node. I have: var parent = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode (xpath) - but this parent always receives a null value (meaning xpath didn't worked).

Comment: OK. post the `C:\\test\\test.xml` file here (the real current xml) I'll point what you did wrong.

Comment: Please check the edited post. I added the generated XML file.

Comment: You'll easily noticed that in your XML a node is inserted wrong position. In the NetFiddle example, your XML have 5 level of `InkZoneProfile`, but your XML you create only have 4 level (one other jump wrong position). That why it is null.

Comment: The last InkZoneProfile is the one inserted.  Others were written before.  I'm trying to insert just after <InkZoneProfile Side="Front">. That's why the node goes 4 level only

Comment: The JSFD file use `ResourceCmdParams`, but your file use `ResourceCMDParams` (cmd vs CMD)

Comment: Change this line: `xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(IZP);` to `parent.AppendChild(IZP);`

Comment: I can't say how much i'm happy for it working. But also i'm embarassed because the main problem was CMD vs Cmd. Other details were wrong because i changed the  code tons of times in order to make it work. Please post it as an answer so i may mark as acceped. Thanks a lot, i really appreciate your help and effort.